# Why can't Rust infer this generic iterator?

Tags: generics, rust, iterator, inference

I have written this code in rust. I want to have a trait with functions that return iterators, I don't want them to be necessarily vectors since it would be nice if they could be implemented as lazy iterators.

```rust
trait Molecule {
    fn atoms<I: Iterator<Item = Atom>>(&self) -> I;
}

fn print_names<M: Molecule>(molecule: M) {
    molecule.atoms().for_each(|atom| {
        println!("Atom: {}", atom.get_name().unwrap_or("Unknown"));
    });
}
```

However this doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/molecules/mod.rs:14:11
   |
14 |     molecule.atoms().for_each(|atom| {
   |              ^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `I` declared on the associated function `atoms`
   |
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
14 |     molecule.atoms::<I>().for_each(|atom| {
   |                   +++++
```

Why doesn't this work? Any type that implements `Iterator<Type = Atom>` will have a function `for_each` that takes as input an `Atom` lambda, right?

I think I heard somewhere something about this being very hard/impossible to implement, but sadly I can't find it. I will probably change the generic iterator to a `Vec` but it would be nice to understand why the compiler can't infer this.

Comment: Each Iterator is implemented by an object, which needs a certain space. If Rust does not know which object that will be, it does not know how much space to reserve for the respective iterator. Therefor it needs to know *which* `Iterator<Item = Atom>` you will be using.

Comment: I think you're looking for `impl Trait`, not generics, and `impl Trait` in traits is indeed currently unstable, although you can emulate it on stable Rust using GATs.